# Executing C# code in Nuget Package

Tags: nuget

I am beginner in creating nuget packages. I created a nuget package which copies all files to solution explorer for now. I am trying to copy folder to users local folder where they have visual studio installed. Can I execute c# code while user installs nuget package on their visual studio solution? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [powershell `.ps1` script and set it to be executed while installing](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal) the nuget package. If Powershell wouldn't suffice ( most probably it would) and you absolutely want to have some piece of C# code run, just include the code in Powershell as described here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx

Comment: Really helpful. I am good to go with using powershell but I am unable to get find out correct relative path code for any users visual studio folder. Any help.